# filter to hide divs by class if class name is contained in an array

Tags: jquery, filter, multi-select

a simplified version of an earlier question.  I'm using a UI multiselector widget to filter products by class. The products will only be visible if their class contains values that match the checked checkbox values.  Easily done if only one checkbox is checked.

the documentation says I can map the values of all checked boxes using this:

```
var checkedValues = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
   return this.value;   
}).get();
```

how can I hide all products except for the one's who's classes match at least one value in that array?  is it possible?  This is not working:

```
$('.main article, .error').hide();
$('.main article[class*=' + checkedValues + ']).show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One convenient way would be to take the list of classes and construct a CSS selector in the form of

```
.class1, .class2, .class3, .etc
```

You can do this extremely easily with code like in your example and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var selector = $("select").multiselect("getChecked")
                .map(function(){return "." + this.value; })
                .get()
                .join();
```

You can then let jQuery do the heavy lifting:

```
$('.main article').filter(selector).show();
```

Comment: Much cleaner than using an array of classes.

Comment: i actually have 5 different multiselectors with different product categories in each. so the products have five classes each. I'm  new to jQuery, but trying to construct the classic [select category 1]   [select category 2]  [select category 3]  [GO!!]  type of form I see on so many ecommerce sites, but trying to do it all client-side.  Maybe i'm using the wrong terminology, but the checkbox values in the multiselector will be mapped to an array, not the classes.  i just want a statement that says "if the product has a class that matches one of the checked box values in the array, show it." ??

Comment: As long as `this.value` is a class name that some products have then the above should work. Did you try it?

Comment: ahh...for some reason half of your code was missing when I first saw the post.  taking a look.  thank you.

Comment: YES!! Thanks, Jon. ".join" is the answer -- a whole day of research comes down to 4 letters.  You're the man.